# auto reference in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto

I have some trouble `about` auto reference.

```
const int i = 1;
auto & ri1 = i; 
auto & ri2 = 1; //error
```

Why is deduced type of `ri1` `const int` but not `ri2`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since `i` has type `const int`, but `1` has type `int`.